# Why did my Django app stop building in App Engine environment

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Recently my app's deployment has stopped building and I cannot figure out why.

My app is a simple app that does some calculations, I've followed deployment instructions and have the same settings from GC tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine).

I am successfully pushing deployments but I think it is not building and launching Django. I have the Cloud Build API enabled.

Any ideas on troubleshooting this would be appreciated

E: Would also like to point out that the size of my deployments have gone down from 60MB to 70KB.

Comment: Can you include build logs, or error messages that are making you think that the application is not deploying? If the deployment size has decreased significantly, it's possible a changed `.gitignore` or `.gcloudignore` file is preventing source code from being deployed.

Comment: Sorry! Just saw this. I'm new to this thing so maybe I'm wrong, I thought it wasn't building because I can see the source files and all in my AE instance, the app just wasn't running. Last time, there were no errors in my logs. I kind of solved my issue by reverting to an old version of my code, the size of my deployments has stayed the same (~70KB) but the app works and runs, I am not sure what I did wrong (or right).